# Is a string acceptable as an int within type Callable?

Tags: python, typing

I would like to know if I have misunderstood the use of `Callable`.

```
def func(f1:int, f2:int, s:str) -> bool:
    return isinstance(f2, int)

def func2(fn:Callable[[int, int, str], bool]):
    print(fn(42.42, '42.42', 'hello mum'))  # Incorrectly passed?

func2(func)
```

I expected my PyCharm IDE to flag the print statement line as a type failure because it supplied (float, str, str) instead of the required (int, int, str). It did not.
However, in the following code the `func` of `func2(func)` is flagged as a type error.

```
def func(f1:int, f2:str, s:str) -> bool:
    return isinstance(f2, int)

def func2(fn:Callable[[int, int, str], bool]):
    print(fn(42, 42, 'hello mum'))

func2(func)  # Correctly flagged as a type error
```

Comment: I think it only checks the function signatures, not the values passed within `func2`? If you only look at the function signatures then in both cases PyCharm flags correctly based on what it can see.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an error or missing functionality with PyCharm. If you use [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/), you correctly get the expected type errors:

```
test.py: note: In function "func2":
test.py:7: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "float"; expected "int"
test.py:7: error: Argument 2 has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```